# Does Matomo/Piwik store any persistent data on the filesystem?

Tags: matomo

Does Matomo/Piwik store any persistent data on the filesystem? I am hoping that apart from the config ini file the rest is all disposable and the persistence is all kept on the database. Is this correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly all Matomo data is stored in the database, so you can delete it and replace it with the latest version without any changes.

There are just a few exceptions:

- `config/config.ini.php`: This file includes important settings and the db connection details. It shouldn't be deleted
- plugins/themes from the marketplace: They get extracted into the plugins folder. Of course you can reinstall them again.
- `/tmp`: Everything in this directory can be deleted without any consequences (apart from a short slowdown when everything is regenerated
- favicon: If you upload a custom favicon/brand logo, it ends up in the `misc/` directory
- geoip database: They are also stored in the `misc/` directory.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you, Lukas. Just a follow-up question then: is config.ini.php changed when someone makes settings changes in the UI or do those go to the DB? And is there a place that states which plugins were installed so I know what to reinstall? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Some user actions in the UI change config.ini.php. The lists of installed and activated plugins are in the config.ini.php